# How to enable https in xampp with centos OS?

Tags: xampp, centos7, virtualhost

I have xampp in `centos 7 OS`, I want to add https on the xampp.

how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these solutions step by step as they suggested.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-6

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-7